# Invalid label in mozilla firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I've a JSP page like this with name test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/json; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
response.setContentType("application/x-javascript");
%>

{"feed": "test"}
```

and an html page where i use jquery for reading the json object.

```
    <html>
    <head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){

    $.getJSON("localhost:8080/test.jsp?callback=?",{test:"test"}, function(data){alert("here");});

    })

    </script>
    </head>
    </body>
    something here
    </body>
    </html>
```

but it shows an error as invalid label in firefox. Can anyone explain me the reason for this error.
I've tried google but could not find a solution or explanation to my problem. What needs do be done for this. Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you setting 2 different content types, Use `application/json` in accordance with `RFC 4627` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type

Comment: Sorry about that.It was a mistake. Nevertheless application/x-javascript is set at last. Both these work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution to the problem by some hit & trial.
It is because when we make getJSON() call on cross domain then response should be wrapped inside a function name. This function is our callback handler for the response in the script.eg

html file :

```
 <html>
    <head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
       $.getJSON("localhost:8080/test.jsp?callback=?");
    }
   function test(data){
      alert(data.feed);
    }
```

And the jsp test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/json; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
response.setContentType("application/x-javascript");
out.write("test({\"feed\": \"test\"})");
%>
```

hope if anybody has the same problemm this will help.you can pass the callback function name as a parameter and make jsp at the server such that it uses that name to wrap the response.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue which was actually because of the some issue with json or ajax call. In your json call it should be {"test":"test"} instead of {test:"test"}.

Try it should work if this is the issue.

Comment: i did that also but seems not the case for the problem. Same invalid error again. Anything else please if you can think of.